# Why Won't Select Box Populate? Noob AJAX Question

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

Please help me get my AJAX demo to work.

Here's the front end code:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Using Ajax and XML With Post</title>

    <script language = "javascript">

      var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; 

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      function getSandwiches1()
      {
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
          XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "sandwiches3.php", 
            true); 
          XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 

          XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
          { 
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
              XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
            var xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;

            var sandwiches 
              = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("sandwich");
            listSandwiches(sandwiches);
            } 
          } 

          XMLHttpRequestObject.send("type=1"); 
        }
      }

      function getSandwiches2()
      {
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
          XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "sandwiches3.php", 
            true); 
          XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 

          XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
          { 
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
              XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
            var xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;

            var sandwiches 
              = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("sandwich");
            listSandwiches(sandwiches);
            } 
          } 

          XMLHttpRequestObject.send("type=2"); 
        }
      }

      function listSandwiches (sandwiches)
      {
        var loopIndex;
        var selectControl = document.getElementById('sandwichList');

        for (loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < sandwiches.length; loopIndex++)
        {
            selectControl.options[loopIndex] = new 
               Option(sandwiches[loopIndex].firstChild.data);
        }
      }
    
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Using Ajax and XML With Post</h1>

    <form>
      <input type = "button" value = "Get sandwiches" 
        onclick = "getSandwiches1()"> 
      <input type = "button" value = "Get vegetarian sandwiches" 
        onclick = "getSandwiches2()"> 
      <select size="1" id="sandwichList">
        <option>Select a sandwich</option>
      </select>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the back end PHP code:

```
<?
header("Content-type: text/xml");
if ($_POST["type"] == "1")
  $sandwiches = array('ham', 'turkey', 'cheese');
if ($_POST["type"] == "2")
  $sandwiches = array('cheese', 'avocado', 'spinach');
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
echo '<sandwiches>';
foreach ($sandwiches as $value)
{
  echo '<sandwich>';
  echo $value;
  echo '</sandwich>';
}
echo '</sandwiches>';
?>
```

The dropdown box isn't populating with sandwiches like it's supposed to. Neither buttons do anything.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, a JS problem, or a HTML problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the back end code, when you use <?php instead of <? it works for me...